# To calculate the integral $\int_{0}^\pi e^{k \cos \theta} \cos(k \sin \theta)d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Question:** let $\Gamma$ be the unit circle $\{e^{i\theta}| 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi\}$. Calculate the integral $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{kz}}{z} dz$ and hence evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^\pi e^{k \cos \theta} \cos(k \sin \theta) d\theta$.

**My answer:** The first one is easy to evaluate you simply look at the function $\frac{e^{kz}}{z}$ and notice that it has a simple pole at 0 and the residue is 1 so the integral is $  2\pi i$. The solution to the next part evades me. So clearly we have to convert the first integral into a form of the second but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $$\int_{0}^\pi e^{k \cos \theta} \cos(k \sin \theta) d\theta + i \int_{0}^\pi e^{k \cos \theta} \sin(k \sin \theta) d\theta = \int_{0}^\pi e^{k( \cos \theta+i\sin \theta)} d\theta.$$ This last integral can easily be computed thanks to $\int_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{kz}}{z} dz$. Then you only have to take the real part.